# Missing rows when querying table with Doctrine (Symfony2)

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine

I'm encountering a strange issue with Doctrine.

I need to query a simple table with only 1 inner join, which I something I have already done many times. But in this case something's odd: there are a lot of rows missing.

I have an entity called Policy. It is linked to a table on my Oracle database. There are 81k+ rows in this table. When querying this entity with the Doctrine query builder, I only get 5k results. I made this query as simple as possible for testing :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('p')->from('ErwMonitoringExtranetBundle:Policy', 'p');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$policiesFull = $query->getResult();
```

The $policiesFull variable only contains 5k elements. There are no duplicates in the table.

The SQL query that is generated by Doctrine looks like this :

```
SELECT
  r0_.node_group_name      AS NODE_GROUP_NAME0,
  r0_.policy_name          AS POLICY_NAME1,
  r0_.policy_description   AS POLICY_DESCRIPTION2,
  r0_.policy_group_name    AS POLICY_GROUP_NAME3,
  r0_.policy_type_name     AS POLICY_TYPE_NAME4,
  r0_.policy_name_on_agent AS POLICY_NAME_ON_AGENT5,
  r0_.date_last_maj        AS DATE_LAST_MAJ6,
  r0_.om_name              AS OM_NAME7,
  r0_.id_node              AS ID_NODE8
FROM
  ewintranet.ref_monitored_ci;
```

Running the same exact query on Oracle returns the full table content.

Counting results through a doctrine query returns the correct number of rows :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('count(p)')->from('ErwMonitoringExtranetBundle:Policy', 'p');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
echo $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

This returns 81k.

Does anybody know why all these rows disappear after using getResult() ?

Comment: the inner join gives only results that are a matching record in both tables

Comment: Every row is matching :)

Comment: did you have the runable query ? so try to execute it on your database directly

Comment: Running the query with the inner join direcly on Oracle returns all the 81k rows. I also tried removing the inner join from the Policy entity and it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: I think about memory limit error. did you have try scalarResult ?

Comment: getSingleScalarResult() on $qb->select('count(p)')->from('ErwMonitoringExtranetBundle:Policy', 'p') returns 81k

Comment: Your posted query does not show any joins?  What do you mean when you say query contains 81K elements?  It's just a query object.  It does not contain any entities.  What does the sql pro filer say?  If it was a memory issue then you would have gotten an error message.

Comment: Okay, so there isn't an inner join in the query because I removed it to make it simpler. The Policy entity contains a ManyToOne link to another entity which I use in my code. I don't believe this is the cause of my issue though, because I tried to remove it and I still had an incorrect number of rows. The SQL profiler doesn't seems to report any errors. What I meant about query containing 81k elements is that using getSingleScalarResult() on it returns 81k. It really looks like my rows disappear when running getResult() or execute() on my query.

Comment: getResult uses a distinct when hydrating objects, i believe, where scalar result does not use distinct.

Comment: I indeed had already encountered this kind of issue in a table with duplicate rows. There are no duplicates in this one though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Check the result using `createQuery` or `createNativeQuery`
2. Run the query from simple php script outside of symfony

If with all 3 methods you get the same issue then it might be problem with the size of data limitation. 
I would start with `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` settings in php.ini

I found also some oracle limitations that might be set at:
oci8.statement_cache_size in php.ini or in file oraaccess.xml in Oracle directory. It is also significant if you use APC for query caching.

Anyway what does app_dev.php say?

Comment: I had already tried using createNativeQuery and I do get all of my rows correctly. This is my backup solution in case I really can't make the query builder work here. I have now tried createQuery and I get the same amount of rows that I get with the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was causing my issue. The primary ID was wrong in my Entity declaration.

The oracle table had a composed primary key while in my entity the ID was only on one column. GetResult was making a DISTINCT on this column.