# Incorrect number of results in query in Symfony using query builder

Tags: sql, oracle, doctrine-orm, symfony

I want to do a query with query builder in Doctrine in Symfony connecting to an Oracle database. I was trying to get results for any bookings that are current, using this code in the controller:

```
$bookRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:VScheduledRoomActivity');
$now = new \DateTime();
$curBookDataQuery = $bookRepo->createQueryBuilder("c");
$curBookDataQuery
    ->where('c.startStamp < :now')
    ->andWhere('c.endStamp > :now')
    ->setParameter('now', $now)
;
$curBookData = $curBookDataQuery->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This should return all current bookings, which should have been 5 (I ran effectively the same query in Oracle SQL Developer) but only 1 came back. I mucked around with the query and always got less results than I am meant to.

So then I thought what if I compare a findAll to query builder with nothing in it. So I modified the code to look like this:

```
$bookRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:VScheduledRoomActivity');
$curBookDataQuery = $bookRepo->createQueryBuilder("c");
$curBookData = $curBookDataQuery->getQuery()->getResult();
$curBookData2 = $bookRepo->findAll();
```

So when I use dump() to check what was returned, there was 15 results for $curBookData and 915 for $currBookData2. These should be exactly the same result!

Has anyone had this problem or have any idea how to solve it?

UPDATE:
I have found some more information, and I believe its to do with the ID. At [Missing rows when querying table with Doctrine (Symfony2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297800/missing-rows-when-querying-table-with-doctrine-symfony2) I see that it was an issue with the primary key, and when I looked into it, Doctrine had set the primary key (I am doing database first) as a field named occurrence_no. This is not a key as its used to track repeat bookings (its and integer), the primary key is activity_id. So I used

```
@ORM\Id
```

on this field to set it as the primary key. This then changed it to 9 results. I saw that it had a type of string, so I edited the lines:

```
@var string
@ORM\Column(name="ACTIVITY_ID", type="string", nullable=true)
```

to

```
@var guid
@ORM\Column(name="ACTIVITY_ID", type="guid", nullable=false)
```

and added

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
```

Now it is showing 67 results! I think it is something to do with the primary key being a GUID as the number of results changed as I edit these details.

Another note: This is a view, and I have used

```
@ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
```

to make sure it is read only.

Comment: Have a look at the executed query in the debug toolbar/profiler and try to execute that one directly in the database.

Comment: What is your value of $now, if it is accurate to just minute for example, you could have a load of records that are not less then or greater then - but equal to

Comment: Gerry: I have used ->getSQL() and taken the SQL statement into Oracle SQL Developer and run it, and got the 915 it should be, so the statement is correct. Rooneyl: The value of $now is fine, dumped it and copied it into SQL developer to check it was correct and got the correct responses. I have found something else and will put an update in the question with new info.

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem solved. First a few things to note for anyone that gets stuck in future:
- When using query builder, check that the ID is set on the correct field
- Check that if you use a GUID, the field is set to GUID and not string (which if you use automatic mapping of the database it will do)
- If you use composite keys, make sure you have the ID set on both, you DONT use a generatedValue and you set up the constructor (see below)

So the solution in this situation....

Problem 1 - I was using a view someone else had created, and presumed the GUID was a primary key. This was a bad assumption and it was a composite key with an integer as the second part of the key.
Problem 2 - The data had somehow made a few duplicates by the time it got to the view, so some of the composite keys were not unique. After refreshing the data further up the line it seemed to bring through the correct values.

Query Builder background:
From some research I see that using something like findAll() will work in situations where the primary key is not unique. However, Query Builder makes the results DISTINCT by primary key, so if your primary key is not defined properly or for some reasons are doubled up, then you will not get any rows that have duplicates.

To set up the composite key, I did:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="OCCURRENCE_NO", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $occurrenceNo;

/**
 * @var guid
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="ACTIVITY_ID", type="guid", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $activityId;

public function __construct($occurrenceNo, $activityId)
{
    $this->occurrenceNo= $occurrenceNo;
    $this->activityId= $activityId;
}
```

For more information on composite keys: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Note that I did see in the Doctrine documentation that only strings and integers can be used for composite keys, however, I have found so far that the GUID works fine (I'm thinking it should be fine from Doctrine 2.1 on).